# How to generate Typescript definitions from AppSync GraphQL schema if I am not using amplify?

Tags: typescript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, graphql-codegen

I have my AppSync api set up using aws-cdk and am not using their amplify framework. I am trying to figure out how / if I can generate Typescript definitions from my AppSync `schema.graphql` file while not using amplify, i.e. no access to `amplify codegen` command. I did try installing and running it, but I assume amplify expects files to be located in certain directories, hence failing.

I looked into https://graphql-code-generator.com but it wont work due to special types AppSync uses like `AWSDateTime`, a work around for this is to have api published and get schema from a graphql endpoint, but this is not ideal i.e. I'd like to be able and generate these types locally without publishing the schema.

Is this doable?

Comment: I am also using the CDK outside of the amplify workflow. I used:
 "amplify add codegen --apiId xxxxxxxxx" 
... which allows selection of Typescript as a generation option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's some custom scalars (like `AWSDateTime`) that aren't part of your `schema.graphql` file, you can just create a separate file like `scalars.graphql` and add those missing type definitions yourself:

```
scalar AWSDateTime
scalar AWSPhone
scalar AWSJSON
```

Then just pass a glob to GraphQL Code Generator that matches both files -- they'll be combined into a single schema.